# Heating and Fan control issues on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, fan, overheating, fancontrol

My Alienware m15 R5 has an overheating problem because the fans are not working.

Here is the output from `sudo pwmconfig`:

```
# pwmconfig version 3.6.0
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

Here is what I get when I run `sudo sensors-detect`:

```
# sensors-detect version 3.6.0
# System: Alienware Alienware m15 Ryzen Ed. R5 [1.2.0] (laptop)
# Board: Alienware 006PVP
# Kernel: 5.11.0-27-generic x86_64
# Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics (25/80/0)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): yes
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 17h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Hygon Family 18h thermal sensors...                         No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             No
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): yes
/dev/port: Operation not permitted

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): yes
/dev/port: Operation not permitted

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): yes
Using driver `i2c-piix4' for device 0000:00:14.0: AMD KERNCZ SMBus

Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes
Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
Some addresses won't be probed.
Client at address 0x2c can not be probed - unload all client drivers first!

Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 0 at ff00 (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes

Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 2 at ff00 (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes

Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 1 at ff20 (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes

Next adapter: AMDGPU DM i2c hw bus 0 (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 1 at 1:00.0 (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 5 at 1:00.0 (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 6 at 1:00.0 (i2c-7)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: NVIDIA i2c adapter 8 at 1:00.0 (i2c-8)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: AMDGPU DM aux hw bus 0 (i2c-9)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Sorry, no sensors were detected.
This is relatively common on laptops, where thermal management is
handled by ACPI rather than the OS.
```

This laptop runs dual boot and there's no issues when I'm running Windows 10. The heating problem only happens in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.